# Current OAuth 1.0 spec - how does it address the session fixation attack?

Tags: oauth, session-fixation

I've implemented an OAuth 1.0 provider following [this specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849), which should be the latest. The specification was amended to address the [session fixation attack that was identified in 2009](http://oauth.net/advisories/2009-1/). The thing is, short of having to diff the two specifications I am unsure as to what measures were added/changed in the spec in response to the issue.

Since I implemented the "right" spec I am having a hard time explaining to stakeholders what measures I have taken to ameliorate the risks.

Anyone care to shed some light on the issue for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.0a addresses a very specific attack described here:

[Explaining the OAuth Session Fixation Attack](https://web.archive.org/web/20130115133512/http://hueniverse.com/2009/04/explaining-the-oauth-session-fixation-attack/)

Comment: The man himself answers! I've read that great post from top to bottom a couple of times, and I really understand the attack vector. However, I may be a little daft here - I cannot fully grasp what it is that has changed between 1.0 and 1.0a that addresses it. Is it the addition of the oauth_verifier?

Comment: Yep. To address the attack, we needed to add something that can bind the user authorizing access to the user retuning to the client. Note that the verifier acts as a bearer token and if it is captured by an attacker (a different vector), it can still take over the authentication grant (so use SSL/TLS for the client callback endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

1. The `oauth_callback` parameter is now required in the request token generation step. The `oauth_callback_accepted` response parameter indicated OAuth 1.0a is being used.
2. The `oauth_verifier` parameter is generated by the service provider during the authentication/consent phase.
3. The `oauth_verifier` must be sent at the access token generation step.

See http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238555/Signed%20Callback%20URLs for more details.